# C++ unordered_map initialization read access violation

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, malloc

I have a struct:

```
struct Foo
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> info;
    int count;
    int bar;
}
```

I am trying to initialize this struct on the heap as follows:

```
Foo* createFoo(int count, int bar)
{
    Foo* foo = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
    foo->info = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>(); // <- exception thrown here
    foo->count = count;
    foo->bar = bar;
    return foo;
}
```

I am getting the following exception thrown upon construction of the `unordered_map`:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation. _Pnext was 0xCDCDCDD1.
```

I understand that MVS fills heap allocated memory with `0xCD` which is why the `_Pnext` pointer has this value, but I don't understand why the `unordered_map` constructor isn't zero-ing these fields out.

I realize that the modern C++ way of doing this is with `new`/constructors but I am trying to write this code in a non-OOP procedural way with (basically) POD objects.

Am I initializing the map incorrectly?

Comment: A `unordered_map` is by no means a POD-type. Why do you try it this way when you know how it _should_ be done?

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but C++ is not an OOP language but rather allows OOP features - are you saying that there is no way of initializing an unordered_map in place like this?

Comment: Using `new` is not the "modern" way; it is and has always been *the* way, ever since C++ was called "C with classes". It also has absolutely nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: @chips C++ is multiparadigm language, OOP is one of the paradigms it enables. And it's not about initializing `std::unordered_map`, you have a problem with initializing `Foo`. Initialization of `Foo` will initialize all of its members.

Comment: May I recommend a good [C++ Book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Will save a ton of time.

Comment: _Am I initializing the map incorrectly?_  You are not initializing the map at all.

Answer (score 1):

A C call of malloc

```
Foo* foo = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
```

does not invoke constructors for data members.

So the data member

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> info;
```

was not constructed.

And this statement with the copy assignment operator

```
foo->info = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>();
```

results in undefined behavior because there is not created the object `foo->info`.

You have to use the operator new instead of malloc.

For example

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
```

Comment: is there no way to manually invoke the unordered_map constructor in place?

Comment: @chips Why are you trying to search non standard ways to allocate an object?

Comment: @chips You can use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) like `new(&foo->info) std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;`

Comment: @MikeCAT that is the answer to my question - thank you

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` do not initialize allocated memory and this is bad when allocating objects that have non-trivial constructors.

You should use `new` instead.

```
Foo* foo = new Foo;
```

To deallocate objects allocated via `new`, you can use `delete`.

```
delete pointe_to_object;
```

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` doesn't create any object. It just reserves some uninitialized memory. There are no objects in that memory, those would have to be created with placement `new`.

Now, `operator=` requires an existing object, because it's a member function (always). By calling this operator on line `foo->info = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>()` you call operator on non-existing object.

The solution is to not go against the language and use `new` as you are supposed to:

```
Foo* createFoo(int count, int bar)
{
    Foo* foo = new Foo;
    // unnecessary now, the object is already constructed and default-initialized
    // foo->info = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>(); 

    // ints are constructed, but not initialized
    foo->count = count;
    foo->bar = bar;
    return foo;
}
```

You could also use `malloc` with placement `new`, but that's only useful if you need memory without actual objects (e.g. in vector implementation).

---

Note: it's a bad smell to use raw `new` in modern C++ (well, 9 years old, but as modern as `std::unordered_map`). Use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory) and STL containers instead.

Comment: as far as I was aware all new does is allocate the memory and then call the default constructor (is this not correct?) if it does then I still don't see why the default constructor can't be invoked manually in place....

Comment: @chips It's incorrect. You are describing behaviour of `new`, `malloc` only allocates memory, nothing more. And you can invoke constructor manually, using placement `new`, as explained in comment under some other answer. But you are trying to invoke `operator=`, not just default constructor, this is UB.

Comment: I understand what malloc does. I've just noticed the placement new comment which answers my question. If operator= is UB not sure why my compiler isn't calling me all sorts of names.

Comment: UB means "anything can happen". A crash (like when using not initialized non-POD structure) or seemingly working correct (like when using not initialized `int`) are both perfectly fine examples of UB. If compiler was obliged to point out UB, it would not be UB anymore.